# Matplotlib plt.show() doesn't display anything

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create a barchart for my dataframe but it doesn't show up, so I made this small script to try out some things and this does display the barchart the way i want. The dataframe is structured the exact same way (I assume) as my big script where all my data is transformed.

Even if I copy paste this code in my other script it doesn't show the the plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'soortfout':['totaalnoodstoppen','aantaltrapopen','aantaltrapdicht','aantalrectdicht','aantalphotocellopen','aantalphotocelldicht','aantalsafetyedgeopen', 'aantalsafetyedgeclose'],
    'aantalfouten':[19,9,0,0,10,0,0,0],
})

print(df)
df.plot(kind='bar',x='soortfout',y='aantalfouten')
plt.show()
```

I can't really paste my other code in here since it's pretty big. But is it possible that other code that doesn't even use anything from matplotlib interferes with plotting a chart?

I've tried most other solutions like:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "Qt4Agg"
```

Currently using Pycharm 2.5

It does work when i use Jupyter notebook.

I was importing modules that i wasn't using so they were grayed out.

But apparently you shouldn't use `import pandas_profiling` if you want to plot with matplotlib

Comment: Your minimal working example does work for me (using PyCharm as well).

Comment: Really? 
If i just copy paste this it should work:
https://gyazo.com/c1ad76d0c854afe16fba7d6f2782236b

Comment: So it does show it to you too right?

Comment: yeh but if i copy and paste it into my other script it doesn't. Even if delete all the other code so it looks exactly the same.
I am going to try to copy paste my code in a jupyter notebook and see if it works there

Comment: Even when I full copy paste my code in jupyter it does show the graph? I really don't understand what's going on here

Comment: Probably you are deactivating the backend of matplotlib at some point in you code. Double check that.

Comment: @b-fg I've found the solution, but I have to wait 2 days to accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't import modules that can interfere with plotting like `pandas_profiling`